# post entire form php

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm creating a script on my website to echo the contents of an entire form. My html code looks like this:

```html
<form action ="forma.php" method ="POST" name="FORM-TXT">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
          <input type="submit" name="submitsave" value ="Submit">
</form>
```

My PHP code looks like this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//use the html Name element to attach html to php scripts
//V-----------------=|txt file codes|=-----------------V
$text = $_POST["FORM-TXT"];
echo $text; 
?>
```

When I run the form, this error is thrown:

> Notice: Undefined index: FORM-TXT in
>   /homepages/31/d585123241/htdocs/mail/forma.php on line 7

How can I make it so the entire form echos, but no specific elements are referenced, only the form.

Comment: You can't pass an entire form like that.  `var_dump` your $_POST so you can see which keys/value pairs actually get passed.

Comment: $_POST contains data from `<input>`, `<select>` etc... data fields. there is no "all form data in a single field" option in http.

Comment: um... I'm just learning php. In what part of the php would I dump?

Comment: @Marc B I'm ok with having the other data mixed in, I can work on that later.

Comment: Try `print_r($_POST)`. [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @EatPeanutButter says

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    //use the html Name element to attach html to php scripts

    //V-----------------=|txt file codes|=-----------------V
    $text = $_POST;

    var_dump($text); 

    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Testing it out...

Comment: ok, It works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't print out HTML that way. However, you can do one of two things:

1) Turn the entire HTML string into a variable, like so:

```
$form = <<<HTML
        <form action ="forma.php" method ="POST" name="FORM-TXT">
          First name:<br>
          <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
          Last name:<br>
          <input type="text" name="lastname">
                  <input type="submit" name="submitsave" value ="Submit">
        </form>
HTML;

echo $form;
```

The other way is to simply close the php tag right after your logic, and the form will display automatically:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//use the html Name element to attach html to php scripts
//V-----------------=|txt file codes|=-----------------V 
?>

<form action ="forma.php" method ="POST" name="FORM-TXT">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
          <input type="submit" name="submitsave" value ="Submit">
</form>
```